# Reference to an upper bound of binomial coefficient

Tags: reference-request, binomial-coefficients, upper-lower-bounds, gaussian

In my project I needed an upper bound of binomial coefficient in terms of the gaussian density, so I derived the inequality

$$ \frac{1}{2^n} \binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}t} \leq \sqrt\frac{2}{n\pi} e^{-(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n})t^2} $$

which holds for any $n\geq 1$ and $|t| \leq \sqrt{n}$.

Note that this bound is asymptotically tight at least in the regime $t=o(n^{1/4})$, which can be proved using the Stirling's approximation. But I needed an explicit and uniform upper bound that always works, so this is what I came up with.

I am pretty sure this kind of upper bound has already been studied in the literature, although a quick googling did not reveal anything. I would greatly appreciate for any help!

Comment: The keyword you might need is Hoeffding's inequality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality

Comment: I needed it in my paper with Nilotpal Sinha: http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/u99/u99.pdf

Comment: @SungjinKim, Thank you for the suggestion, but I think the Hoeffding's inequality is not exactly what I want in my case. In fact, my original approach adopted the Hoeffding's inequality to bound the tail regime for the binomial sum I am studying, and then used the Stirling's approximation for the CLT regime. But this involved painful estimations, and now I plan to use this local-limit-theorem-type inequality instead. In this approach, the extra $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ factor really becomes a life-saver, so that's why I am looking for a reference to this seemingly less known variant.

Comment: In this case, I had Lemma 5.2 in my paper for individual term estimates. But, I played safe by assuming $|g(x)|\leq 6\log x$ there. So, I think it boils down to how far we expand the Maclaurin series of the logarithm. $g(x)$ in my paper is essentially $t$ in your estimate. As it stands, yours looks stronger.

Comment: @SungjinKim I agree. I am mostly interested in the range $|t|\leq n^{1/4}$ for an optimal result, and if I remember correctly from my computation, I indeed need more terms from the Maclaurin series for my purpose. Anyway, thank you for the link! It seems that people simply re-derive this kind of estimate again and again when they need it.

Comment: Dear downvoter, would you kindly point out why my answer is being downvoted so that I can improve the quality of my question?